# Use firebase analytics, to log and see individual users last login time

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

Can I use firebase event logging OR user properties logging OR other firebase feature to record user last login time and then see individual user data. I am only able to see collective/all users data altogether in firebase console, if i do event logging or  user properties.

I know I can maintain this data in realtime db/firestore, but is there a better way than this.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Analytics is not designed to track individual users.  In fact, the [terms of service](https://firebase.google.com/terms/analytics#7_privacy) prohibit logging personally identifiable information.